# Почему не открывает zip файл который я принимаю по httpurlconnection?

Tags: java, android, zip

Принимаю с сервера `zip` архив, потом вручную через файл менеджер нахожу этот архив, пробую его разархивировать и получаю сообщение о том, что файл поврежден.

Хотя если ссылку по которой загружаю файл ставлю в браузер и загружаю через браузер то все загружается и открывается...

Я так понимаю, что проблема где то именно в коде когда я принимаю и сохраняю файл на устройстве...

вот код, что я делаю не так?

**P.S.** Используя этот код я получал с сервера просто файлы(с расширением `.dae`), но вот попробовал принять `.zip` и ничего его не открывает...

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    HttpURLConnection conn = getHttpURLConnection(url);
    File avatarModelFile = getFile(getAvatarModelDir(context));
    byte[] data = receiveByteResponseFromConnection(conn, context);
    writeFile(avatarModelFile, data);
    return null;
}

private static HttpURLConnection getHttpURLConnection(URL url) {

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;

    try {
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            conn.connect();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return conn;
}

 private File getFile(File path) {
    return new File(path.getPath() + File.separator + UtilClass.getAvatarName(context) + ".zip");
}

private static byte[] receiveByteFromConnection(HttpURLConnection conn, Context context) {
    int contentLength = conn.getContentLength();
    InputStream is = getInputStream(conn);

    if (isProgressBarAvailable(contentLength)) {
        String charset = getCharSet(conn);
        return getBytesFromConnection(context, contentLength, charset, is).getBytes();

    } else {
        return getBytesFromConnection(is);
    }
}

@NonNull
private static byte[] getBytesFromConnection(Context context, double contentLength, InputStream is) {
    byte[] data = new byte[1024];
    int totalRead = 0;
    int bytesRead;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        if (is != null) {
            while ((bytesRead = is.read(data)) > 0) {

                sb.append(new String(data, 0, bytesRead));


                totalRead += bytesRead;
                int progress = (int) (totalRead * (100 / contentLength));
                new ProcessBarNotification(context).updateProcessNotification(progress);
            }
            new ProcessBarNotification(context).lastProcessNotification();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sb.toString().getBytes();
}
```

**ПРАВКА**

После того как убрал `charset` и

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

Закачал архив заново и попробовал открыть в текстовом редакторе. Редактор написал такую ошибку

> The file /home/aleksey/Downloads/My Avatar.zip was opened with UTF-8 encoding but contained invalid characters.
>   It is set to read-only mode, as saving might destroy its content.
>   Either reopen the file with the correct encoding chosen or enable the read-write mode again in the menu to be able to edit it.

и вот так это выглядит

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А зачем вам чарсет при работе с бинарными данными?

Comment: судя по тексту, пытаетесь загрузить json. Я бы файл открыл любым редактором и посмотрел. Вполне возможно,там либо html страница, либо что то более интересное.

Comment: @PinkTux Не могу сказать точно... Я взял это из примера... Да и впринцепи этот код работал когда я принимал файл, а теперь когда сервер отправляет zip то почему то не открывает его...

Comment: @KoVadim не до конца понял, что вы имеете ввиду... Почему `json`? Сервер отправляет `zip` который содержит 2 файла, один с расширением `.dae` второй `.png`...

Comment: вы зачем-то конвертируете принятые данные в строку, в процессе те байты, которые не получается декодировать в символы, отбрасываются или заменяются на вопросики. Нужно просто взять и перекачать `conn.inputStream` в `FileOutputStream` - http://stackoverflow.com/a/3223510/5661663

Comment: ну мало чего там сервер отправляет по **Вашему мнению**. Вполне возможно, что он присылает что то другое. Поэтому я и пишу - возьмите скачанный файл и не пытайтесь его открыть архиватором, а попытайтесь открыть текстовым редактором.

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko,  уберите для начала обработку чарсета. Вы вообще никак не должны влиять на содержимое принятого файла. Ну и `Content-Type` из запроса убрать, в крайнем случае заменить на `application/x-zip` или `application/octet-stream`

Comment: @KoVadim я 100% знаю что отправляет сервер и + как я описал в вопросе если я качаю этот архив через браузер то все открывается, не открывается только если я качаю этот архив на свой девайс. А насчет архиватора, тоже самое я описал в вопросе что никакие архиваторы не открывают файл... Пишет, что файл поврежден

Comment: Сервер может отправлять совершенно разные данные для "Content-Type", "application/json". По этому я бы на вашем месте не был так уверен в том, что сервер вам отправляет, не проверив точно

Comment: То, что в браузере все открывается, не значит, что у Вас в андроид приложении получиться. Сервер можен смотреть на куки, на заголовки и многое другое. И выдавать **различные ответы**.
Я был бы на 100% уверен, только если бы запустил сниффер и посмотрел, что там по факту приходит.

Comment: @PinkTux Убрал обработку чарсета и закоментил `Content-Type` , но ничего не поменялось(

Comment: я так понимаю, Вы принципиально не хотите смотреть внутрь файла?

Comment: @metalurgus дополнил вопрос

Comment: @KoVadim нет, все проверил, вопрос дополнил, но все равно не пойму, что нужно сделать...

Comment: судя по содержимому - битый zip архив. И причина, как по мне, проста - Вы пытаетесь запихнуть бинарные данные в строку (об этом выше уже писали). Поищите код для скачивания бинарных файлов (картинок, к примеру).

Comment: @zRrr да ваш совет помог, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге вот этот метод заработал , спасибо @zRrr... И что интересно, что размер файла после приема в 2 раза меньше...

```
private void writeFile(File file, HttpURLConnection connection) {
    InputStream input = getInputStream(connection);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int n;

    OutputStream output = null;
    try {
        output = new FileOutputStream(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        if (input != null) {

            while ((n = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {

                if (output != null) {

                    output.write(buffer, 0, n);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {

        if (output != null) {
            output.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```